# What is the correct terminology for each "step" in a Bootstrap layout (e.g. phone step, tablet step, desktop step). Is it "step" or something else?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the correct terminology for each "step" in a Bootstrap layout (e.g. phone step, tablet step, desktop step).

The phone "step" condenses the menu down to the button, while the desktop "step" has the menu items all expanded in the header.

Are they called "steps" or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much a Bootstrap thing but a rather general term in the field of responsive webdesign, where these are referred to as "breakpoints".

Comment: Thanks.  Being a back-end programmer, however, I have to say that "breakpoints" is a horrible name for this, since "breakpoints" already mean something very different in programming (e.g. setting a breakpoint in some code where the compiler stops, and that you can continue onward from).  You UI/front end guys should really use a different term for this, if in fact "breakpoint" is commonly used.  edit: I think "step" is a good, descriptive term that you could use.

Comment: Since I'm a backend developer myself (most of the time), I know what a breakpoint in programming is :) (even though I'd say it's a debugger that stops there rather than the compiler). But I promise I'll tell all UI/front end guys I know to call their breakpoints "steps" from now on :) Have a nice weekend.